# PostGIS 2.0.0 install GEOS issue

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Trying to install PostGIS 2.0.0 on Ubuntu 11.10.  I've basically followed the OSGeo instructions found here: http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/UsersWikiPostGIS20Ubuntu1110src.  I built GEOS 3.3.3.  If I type `geos-config --version` into the terminal, I am returned `3.3.3`.

I can run `./configure` and `make` without issue.  `./configure` ends with:

```
 PostGIS is now configured for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 

-------------- Compiler Info -------------  
 C compiler:           gcc -g -O2 
 C++ compiler:         g++ -g -O2 

-------------- Dependencies --------------  
 GEOS config:          /usr/local/bin/geos-config 
 GEOS version:         3.3.3 
 GDAL config:          /usr/local/bin/gdal-config 
 GDAL version:         1.9.0 
 PostgreSQL config:    /usr/bin/pg_config 
 PostgreSQL version:   PostgreSQL 9.1.3 
 PROJ4 version:        47 
 Libxml2 config:       /usr/bin/xml2-config 
 Libxml2 version:      2.7.8 
 JSON-C support:       no 
 PostGIS debug level:  0 
 Perl:                 /usr/bin/perl 

--------------- Extensions ---------------  
 PostGIS Raster:       enabled 
 PostGIS Topology:     enabled 

-------- Documentation Generation --------  
 xsltproc:             /usr/bin/xsltproc 
 xsl style sheets:      
 dblatex:               
 convert:               
 mathml2.dtd:          http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/mathml2.dtd
```

All looks good, right?  But here's the problem.  When I run `make test`, the build fails with this at the end:

```
Creating spatial db postgis_reg
createlang: language "plpgsql" is already installed in database "postgis_reg"
Preparing spatial db postgis_reg

 Something went wrong during db initialization (core module).
 For details, check /tmp/pgis_reg/regress_log

make[1]: *** [check] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/anthony/Downloads/postgis-2.0.0/regress'
make: *** [check] Error 1
```

Inside `/tmp/pgis_reg/regress_log` is:

```
SET
BEGIN
psql:/home/anthony/Downloads/postgis-2.0.0/regress/00-regress-install/share/contrib/postgis/postgis.sql:69: ERROR:  could not load library "/home/anthony/Downloads/postgis-2.0.0/regress/00-regress-install/lib/postgis-2.0.so": /home/anthony/Downloads/postgis-2.0.0/regress/00-regress-install/lib/postgis-2.0.so: undefined symbol: GEOSRelatePatternMatch
```

I've tried to ignore the issue and go forward, running `sudo make install` but when I get to setting up my db with `psql -d infinitydb -f postgis.sql` I get a similar problem:

```
SET
BEGIN
psql:postgis.sql:69: ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/postgis-2.0.so": /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/postgis-2.0.so: undefined symbol: GEOSRelatePatternMatch
```

I've looked around on the net, found one other person with the `GEOSRelatePatternMatch` problem but his was due to multiple GEOS installs.  As far as I'm aware, I only have one.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PostGIS is trying to load the symbols from a different geos library then the one it was compiled with. Search for *geos* on your system, remove them all and recompile.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is due to postgis thinking the libraries are in a different location on your server then what they actually are.  I had this same error with packages I got from Ubuntu GIS.  They were installed to /usr/lib, but for some reason postgis was looking for them in /usr/local/lib.  Either way, I ran 'ldconfig' and ran the test again, and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into that issue a while back when writing these instructions, and [submitted a bug](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/1685) for it. I've tried fixing it, but gave up, therefore there is a known limitation for `make test`. (I'd be eager to figure out the problem with the test and re-open the ticket, there are any pointers out there. Probably something to do with the Makefile, as it is mixing the version of GEOS with GDAL.)

Despite the failure with `make test`, your install should work without this issue, so I'd continue on to the next steps and install.