# undefined symbol: GEOSRelatePatternMatch

Tags: pattern-matching, ubuntu-12.04, postgresql-9.1, postgis, geo

Trying to add the postgis extension to postgresql but getting the error;

ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/postgis-2.1.so": /usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/lib/postgis-2.1.so: undefined symbol: GEOSRelatePatternMatch

Any suggestions as to what this means? I can't access the .so to have a look but the file is there in the direcoty specified in the error.

Environment is Ubuntu 12.4

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543552/postgis-2-0-0-install-geos-issue Geos problems are often caused by conflicts existing from  older versions, or the libs being in the wrong place.

Comment: What steps did you do to install PostGIS and dependencies?

Comment: cd ~/Downloads

wget http://download.osgeo.org/postgis/source/postgis-2.1.3.tar.gz

mkdir ~/src

mv postgis* ~/src

tar -xvzf postgis*

cd postgis*

sudo apt-get install libpq-dev

sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.1

sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev

sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev

sudo apt-get install gdal-bin

sudo apt-get install libproj-dev

./configure

make

sudo make install

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the following installs;

sudo apt-get install libpq-dev sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.1 sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev sudo apt-get install libgdal-dev sudo apt-get install gdal-bin sudo apt-get install libproj-dev

Then purged postgis;

sudo dpkg --purge postgis postgresql-9.1-postgis

After that I went through the installaltion process again.

Now it works fine